# Stuck on writing a proof.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am taking a discrete math class, and am still really new to writing proofs. I was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem. I am pretty confused on what it is even asking.

Here is the problem:

Let $x$, $y \in \mathbb{Z}$, and let $n = xy$. Prove that at least one of $x$; $y$ is at most $\sqrt{n}$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens when both of $x$ and $y$ are greater than $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Is that the euro sign?

Comment: Fix $x\geq \sqrt{n}$, to show $y\leq \sqrt{n}$ ask yourself what would happen if $y>\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: I think that a better wording would be “Prove that at least one of the numbers $x$ and $y$ is at most $\sqrt{n}$.” Whose wording was it in the question?

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. It really helped. Sorry for all the confusion on the problem. I didn't know how to do some of the symbols, and the wording came from a worksheet my professor made. I just copied it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is asking you to show that if you multiply two numbers, then one of them is less than the root of the product.

I would say, think about it as if it were two numbers added together. If I have two numbers a+b=c, with all of them being greater than 0. Then of the two addends, at least one of them can be at most, c/2. e.g., if c=6, then at least one of them can be no more than 3. If both of them are greater than 3, then a+b>c.

For your problem, think of 16. Of x and y,  at least one of them is no more than 4.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand what it is saying now.

Comment: @furuf If he helped, you should mark him up.  If he answered your question completely, you should click on his check mark so that we know your question is answered.